# Send data from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can we send data from actvity to fragment? The Fragments are configured to actvity by using FragmentPagerAdapter.

Regards
mini.

Comment: Try this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity

Answer (score 1):

- You can pass a bundle to the fragment on creation with [`setArguments`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29).
- You can create methods to set the data on the Fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this by using  [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Send data from the activity (or fragment) :

```
int a = 5;

Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
args.putInt("INT_DATA_TAG", a); 

Fragment fragment = Fragment.newInstance(args); 
//Making fragment transaction
```

Retrieve data in the fragment

```
int a;
public static Fragment newInstance(Bundle args) {
      a = args.getInt("INT_DATA_TAG"); //use a constant for the tag
      return new Fragment();
}
```