# Data from Fragment to Activity communication not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been at this for a little while and after several abortive attempts, I am very close to achieving what I am after.  I have mined various answers from this site, the most helpful being :-

[Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity)

I have implemented all of Harlo's code snippets into my program but I'm left with one problem.

When I run the app, I tap on the list item to load the "Core" fragment and I get the dreaded "Unfortunately application has stopped" as it crashes.

My fragment code is below and I have highlighted the offending line, I have also included the relevant section of the logcat.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Gary

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class CoreFragment extends Fragment{

int index;
Button Button1,Button2,Button3;
String Str;
OnDataPass dataPasser;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a) {
    super.onAttach(a);
        dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;
}


public static CoreFragment newInstance(int index) {
    CoreFragment coreFragment = new CoreFragment();
    coreFragment.index = index;
    return coreFragment;
}


public interface OnDataPass {
    public void onDataPass(String data);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist. The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed. Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.corefragment,
            container, false);

    Button Button1 = (Button) mRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Str = "I ";
        passData(Str);
            }

       public void passData(String data) {
            data = Str;
            dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
        }

    });
    return mRelativeLayout;
}
}//end
```

LogCat

```
01-18 12:19:18.430: W/dalvikvm(1601): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40acf228)
01-18 12:19:18.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1601): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 12:19:18.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1601): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.epsilonitsystems.fragger.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.epsilonitsystems.fragger.CoreFragment$OnDataPass
01-18 12:19:18.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1601):     at com.epsilonitsystems.fragger.CoreFragment.onAttach(CoreFragment.java:25)
```

Hi TNR,
Thank you for that,as I said new to fragments and they are proving a real pain!! I have added the line you suggest, and I now get a crash!  The LogCat is below.  Thanks for the help so far, I'll be glad to get this one sorted!!

```
01-23 15:30:40.659: W/dalvikvm(3098): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40acf228)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at com.epsilonitsystems.fragger.MainActivity.onDataPass(MainActivity.java:33)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at com.epsilonitsystems.fragger.CoreFragment$1.passData(CoreFragment.java:69)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at com.epsilonitsystems.fragger.CoreFragment$1.onClick(CoreFragment.java:62)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3549)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14393)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-23 15:30:40.749: E/AndroidRuntime(3098):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to TypeCast an Activity to an Interface. So You are getting `ClassCastException`. Check whether your `MainActivity` is implementing `onDataPass` interface or not. If it implements `onDataPass` Interface then your problem is solved. Hope it works.

**Updated Answer:**

change your `onClick()` as below. you have written `passData()` but never called it to pass the Data to `onDataPass()` This will 100% solve your issue for sure.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 Str = "I ";
 passData(Str);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nagaraj436, that cured the crashing. The only problem I have now is that the onDataPass method never seems to get triggered!! I thought I had it in the right place, i.e. within the onClickListener but eclipse has the wiggly yellow line underneath it and says "The method passData(String) from the type new View.OnClickListener(){} is never used locally". Sorry to seem a complete idiot, but how do I get round this please.  This is driving me mad!!

Comment: Sorry to un-accept the answer, but I was hoping for a wee bit more help with the last bit.  I have a feeling that as I accepted the answer from Nagaraj436, people stopped looking at this.  Can anyone help me with the onDataPass method not being fired please?  Thank you all in advance!!

Comment: No response so set back to answered. Still stuck tho so any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Gary Check my updated answer and It will work for sure. if it work then upvote the answer.

Comment: It has just occurred to me.  The CoreFragment is called from another fragment,(although this calling fragment is permanent and CoreFragment is in a frame layout as it will be one of many possible Fragments to be used), does this make a difference to how I need to go about this?

Comment: Hi TNR, thank you for the the solution.  It works now. I had a stupid schoolboy level error in my code in my MainActivity!! I have a new problem now but I will post that one separately!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are making this so complicated.  Why don't you just do this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    ((OnDataPass) CoreFragment.this.getActivity()).passData("I");
}
```

Obviously, of course, the Activity has to be:

```
public class ActivityThatIncludesCoreFragment implements OnDataPass {    
    ....
}
```

Comment: My MainActivity implements OnDataPass, (one question though, I had to import it from the fragment,am I doing something wrong?).  When I add your line to the OnClick handler I get the following error message:- The method passData(String) is undefined for the type CoreFragment.OnDataPass.  This a sending me round the bend!!  Thank you to everyone who has tried to help me fix this. It is very much appreciated!!!

Comment: It has just occurred to me. The CoreFragment is called from another fragment,(although this calling fragment is permanent and CoreFragment is in a frame layout as it will be one of many possible Fragments to be used), does this make a difference to how I need to go about this?

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I finally have it working using TNR's solution. The reason it didn't work is I had a stupid, schoolboy level error in my MainActivity(Hangts head in shame)!!