# How to send data from an activity to a Fragment in Android using interfaces?

Tags: java, android, interface, fragment

The android Fragments tutourial teaches how to send data from a fragment to activity in using `Interfaces`. I don't understand interfaces that much and NOBODY gives a good example of how to use them not even docs.oracle.com. What I want to know is how to recreate something like `LocationListener`, where I:

1) implement the interface in class A

2) set the handler for example :`setInterfaceHandler(this)` in class A

3) add my implementation of the interface in class A foe Example:

```
public void onSomethingHappened(String s)
{
  // do this
}
```

4) periodically have class B fire off events that will be caught by the handler class in A

**For example:** Android will periodically give my activity location updates (Dont know how to do this).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9977370/1339473 see this one... is good tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use Java language mechanisms and design patterns for your purpose (interfaces, handlers, ...) ... or you might have a look at some dedicated Android framework solutions for your problem like:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html
- http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html

With these approaches you are able to fire your events from class B and handle them in class A with a clean and "android like" design.