# Pass String[] from one activity to another

Tags: android, string, bundle

In main activity i send the String[] name like this:

```
private void sendNames() {

    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray("key", names);
    Intent i=new Intent(this, ListFriendsFragment.class);
    i.putExtras(b);

}
```

when i send names it is not empty 100%, and put this code in a method, and called it after the i get the names.

In activity i want to receive the string[] i get it like this:

```
 names = this.getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("key");
```

In both, main activity and the one i want to receive the string, `names` is declared as follows:

```
private String[] names;
```

When i start the activity which should get the `names` the application crashes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.utm.course.friendslist.ListFriendsFragment.PrintNames(ListFriendsFragment.java:26)
at com.utm.course.friendslist.ListFriendsFragment.onCreate(ListFriendsFragment.java:20)
```

What am i doing wrong?

---

**Update**

these are parts where i use `Intent`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (currentSession != null) {
        currentSession.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
...
private void sendNames() {
    Log.d("sendNames", "started");
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putStringArray(key, names);
    Intent i=new Intent(this, ListFriendsFragment.class);
    i.putExtras(b);
}
...
 private void listFriends() {
    Log.d("Activity", "List Friends Activity Starting");
    Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ListFriendsFragment.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `sendNames()` does not return the intent you created and you probably call `startActivity(i);` somewhere else where the intent you created here is no longer in the scope.

Change the signature of `sendNames()` to return the intent you've created and use that intent when you start the activity.

If you'll run with a debugger, add a break point where you start the activity and make sure that the intent you pass is containing that bundle with the "key" string array.

Comment: I have searched for `Intent` in my project. please check the update in the question, as here it will be hard to understand.

Comment: 1. your code doesn't show where the last two methods are getting called from. 2. Like I wrote, the `intent` that you create in `sendNames()` is being destroyed the moment `sendNames()` finish to execute.

Comment: you are right. i put sendNames and listFriends together, and i send the intent when i start the activity. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this way:

Assumption, String[] names;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListFriendsFragment.class);
intent.putExtra("key", names);
startActivity(intent);
```

On next activity,

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String[] names = intent.getStringArrayExtra("key");
```

Comment: the app crashes: `unable to start activity... null pointer exception`

Answer (score 0):

Sending

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(b);
```

Receiving

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Comment: the sending part goes ok without any error. FriendsListFragment is not a fragment, its activity.

still getting NullPointerException on FriendsListActivity