# is it possible to pass a value from FragmentActivity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

is it possible to pass a value from :`FragmentActivity {}` to `Fragment {}`.

Am implemented navigation drawer in my app and the problem is i have categories in the drawer menu. Now i want to pass the category id from public class MainActivity extends `FragmentActivity {}` to public class Galleries extends `Fragment {}`.little help is appreciated 
**Edited :**
guys plz see the links below , i posted  my codes there. Tell me how should i pass the Int pos value from **OnclickListener** in **MainActivity** to the **fragment class Galleries**.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pmcdjb3yorvp54w/MainActivity.txt
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivkc15bqz4vp8c5/fragment%20class.txt

Comment: You have Bundle as solution when you want to communicate from FragmentActivity to Fragment.                     FragmentTransaction ft = context.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  bundle= new Bundle();
  fgmtObject.setArguments(bundle);
  ft.replace(R.id.contentpage, R.id.fragmentPage);
  ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
  ft.addToBackStack(null);
  ft.commit();

Comment: possible duplictae of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity

Comment: What have you tried already? We need to know that you're coming here having already put in some effort on your own to find the solution.

Comment: @Rollno1. its showing  error for context.Error is :context cannot be resolved.

Comment: @sureshbabu : Where are you getting exception i.e which line is giving you error can you paste that set of code.

Comment: @ Rollno1 public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                                   super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView); Galleries obj = new Galleries();
                                   FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); //This line when i add context.getSupportFragmentmanager().

Comment: My code is here.. see that . i just wanna pass a value from drawerclosed() to galleries fragment.https://www.dropbox.com/s/xc9y373qnxyzssx/Rick%20Falck.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than passing data in the Intent Bundle, there is a way to get direct access to a Fragment.

In a FragmentActivity, you use FragmentManager to add your Fragment.

You can also use FragmentManager to get your Fragment (using findById()).  After getting it and casting it to your classname, you can then easily call public methods in your Fragment.

Example:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

fragment.updateData(..);
```

### EDIT

To get data from the passed intent do something like this:

```
Intent in = getActivity().getIntent();
String str = in.getStringExtra(EXTRA_STRING_DATA);
```

The getArguments() is for a Bundle attached to the Fragment, not the one passed in the Intent.

### EDIT2

You can't create the Fragment the way you are doing it.

In your activity do this:

```
FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// int position =5;
String check="checking...";
Galleries fragment = Galleries,newInstance(check);
tx.replace(R.id.main, Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragment));
tx.commit();
```

Create a static method in Galleries:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String check) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("id_cat", check);
    Galleries fragment = new Galleries();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Now you can do getArguments() in onCreateView().

Comment: It will be more helpful if u elobrate your answer with example or else just give any link , that has an good example for that. Anyway thank u for this

Comment: Not much to elaborate here.  You updated your question after I posted this.  Maybe it doesn't apply to your situation.  My answer is how you can send data to a fragment that is already displayed (like your Activity gets gets info from somewhere else and needs to send it on).

Comment: ok. thanx . I will update my MainActivity code. so that u can understand my situation and help me..

Comment: See the edit I made to my answer.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: am trying to put my full code .. it s really hard. shall i mail it to you

Comment: i have created fragment. its working.. but am not able to pass value from mainactivity to galleries(fragment)

Comment: I tried.  Others have down-voted your question, because it shows a lack of understanding the basics.  This is apparently so.  The **Big Nerd Ranch Android book** is what I read to start Android programming.  It covers a lot and is up to date.

Comment: Oh! Its k . Thanx for your help and book. I will read the book for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it.. Actually no need of constructor in Galleries fragment . I removed constructor and received  the value simply by the following code
int throwid = getArguments().getInt("ID"); Log.d("BUNDLE==NULL",String.valueOf(throwid)); 
passed the value by:
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, final int pos,final long id){

```
             final Galleries pass= new Galleries();
              Bundle args = new Bundle();
              args.putInt("ID", pos);
              pass.setArguments(args);
          if (pass!=null){ 
             Log.d("bundle","has value");
           }

                    drawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){
                             @Override 
                             public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView){
                                     super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

                                     //FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                     //tx.replace(R.id.main,Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, fragments[0]));
                                     FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); tx.replace(R.id.main, pass); tx.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

From `FragmentActivity` you can send data to `Fragment` with intent as:

```
FragmentTransaction ftran = context.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("Id", <your id here>);
Galleries fragobj=new Galleries ();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
ftran.replace(R.id.firstpage, R.id.galleryfragmentPage); 
ftran.commit();
```

and get id to next Fragment:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
int myID = bundle.getInt("Id", 0);
```

I do not know what logic you have implmented.
Try out as below:

```
   FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String check="checking...";
bundle.putString("id_cat", check);
Galleries obj =new Galleries();
     obj.setArguments(bundle);
    Log.d("BUNDLE", bundle.toString());
    tx.replace(R.id.main, obj);
tx.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                                    // int position =5;
tx.commit();
```

Comment: This is not working ...check my code and if possible tell me a good solution.https://www.dropbox.com/s/xc9y373qnxyzssx/Rick%20Falck.txt