# Getting data from Fragment upon parent activity Button Click

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

my android app main activity contains two fragments.The main activity also contain two buttons-save and cancel.The fragments contain EditTexts and Spinners.i want to take data from these EditTexts and Spinner upon Save button click event(Event occur in parent activity).Is it Possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity)

Comment: Actually,when i press save button(from parent activity)i want to take data from the current fragment and want to save it.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to get the current fragment by doing `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentId)` that will return the current fragment. You can then check its type by calling `getClass()` or by checking its instance as such `if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentId) instanceof MyFragment){
//Code goes here
}` You can then type cast it if it is the correct class and call whatever methods you want

```
MyFragment fragment=(MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentId);
fragment.getSomeData();
```

Comment: But how can i access user inputs from that fragment?

Comment: What do you mean by user inputs? Like when they press a button?