# Only my main activity can access my switch and not the fragment that it is in

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a navigation drawer Android project that has several fragments. Inside one of the fragment layouts, I have a toggle switch. I have this simple handler stub inside of the fragment activity:

```
public void onCellDataSettingClicked(View view) {
        boolean on = ((Switch) view).isChecked();

        if (on) {
            // Enable vibrate
        } else {
            // Disable vibrate
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I get to this line "boolean on = ((Switch) view).isChecked();" the program crashes. I am unable to access the Switch from my fragment activity. If I place the same code inside of my main activity, everything works.

How do I get my handler to work inside of the associated fragment's activity and not just the main activity?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following you, you just need to make a getter in your parent activity for the `boolean`, then call `getActivity().isMyBooleanName()` from your fragment. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity).