# Android - Using Android Studio default ViewPager setup to pass data between an Activity and Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am looking into passing data between an `Activity` (`ActionBarActivity`) to a `Fragment`. Currently, I am testing using the generated code from Android Studio (only thing added is the `TextView` showing the fragment number).

I've seen answer pointing to using a bundle, however it would not seem to work in this case as the bundle is created within the fragment itself rather than the parent `Activity`. In this scenario, with the default implementation, how would you pass the data. Alternatively, without straying too far away from the base, what would be an alternative?

**MainActivity.java (contains the activity, adapter and demo fragment)**

```
package com.blah.fragmentswitchingtest;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    public String stringToCarry = "String"; // How would I carry this string to into the Fragment

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        protected TextView mSectionLabel;
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            mSectionLabel = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);


            Integer myValue = this.getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            String blah = myValue.toString();

            mSectionLabel.setText(blah);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're trying to pass an integer (sectionNumber), you could use SharedPreferences [Default SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: It's not the sectionNumber, the sectionNumber's being carried fine within the Bundle, but the problem is the Bundle is created in the Fragment itself, so I can't carry anything over from the MainActivity. 

I've edited and added a String (stringToCarry) in the MainActivity, how would this be carried over.

Comment: I think you need to create a Bundle in the Activity, and then get the string in the Fragment itself: [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21103316/3342430)

Comment: That'd be ideal Freddie, but I can't seem to get it to work moving the public static PlaceholderFragment to the Activity rather than fragment.

Comment: Hmm...alright then I think you should take a look at Johan's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi an easy solution is to create a public static class in the main activity and access its properties from the fragments

Another is to implement callbacks

For example in the main activity you create a static class like so :

```
public static class MyData{

String mName;
String mSurname;

public MyData(String mName, String mSurname) {
    this.mName = mName;
    this.mSurname = mSurname;
}


public String getmName() {
    return mName;
}


public String getmSurname() {
    return mSurname;
}
```

}

Also in the Main Activity we have a public static Array holding data items :

```
public static ArrayList<MyData>mData = new ArrayList<>();
```

In the OnCreate Main Activity we populate the data :

```
mData.add(new MyData("John","Doe"));
mData.add(new MyData("Peter","Pan"));
```

From the fragments we can access data like so :

```
ArrayList<MainActivity.MyData>list = MainActivity.mData;

for(MainActivity.MyData obj : list){
    Log.d("DATA", obj.getmName() + " " + obj.getmSurname());

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works well, however for carrying just a single piece of data you could use http://stackoverflow.com/a/22065903/1544797

Comment: yes in fact there are many ways to get data around, still i dont prefer to create an instance of the main activity when you can have the main activity exposing its properties.