# Android how to send objects to new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

I want to send some Data from a fragment to a new fragment. I know this can be done with a bundle but I don't know how to use them, especially not with my own objects.

I replace my old fragment with a new one like this:

```
Fragment newFragment = new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack("saveState");
transaction.commit();
```

So now I want to send this Data to the "newFragment".

```
private List<MyObject> objectList;
```

How can I put this objectList to a new Bundle?

**EDIT:**

And also, how can I send the bundle from my old fragment to the newFragment?

Comment: Please read: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Well now I know how to pass the data with the host activity to the new fragment, but I still does not know how to put the objectList to the bundle?

Comment: Pass through constructor? Pass via interface? Did you even read information the link provided?

Comment: Well it's not strongly recommended to create a non-default constructor in a subclass, so sending data through constructor is not even the best solution. So the given information on the site is to use setArgument(Bundle) but there is still the problem that I don't know how to put the list in the bundle and the site don't give me this information.

Comment: Once again, please read what I said in my comment and the link. To make things more clear, here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9977370/950427.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom Object must implement Parcelable. Parcelable is a way to tell Android how the reconstruct custom Objects when passed through a Bundle.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Once your Object implements Parcelable, you can put your list in the Bundle using putParcelableArrayList(String key, ArrayList value)

It is a bit tricky the first time, but you'll get there =)
There is plenty of tutorials available.

Answer (score 0):

Use GSON library:

- https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ -- library;
- http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html -- tutorial;

Comment: I'm still using GSON library.