# Pass data from fragment to viewpager

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I have Fragment and want send data to Viewpager. I tried to use Bundle but when don't work.

NewRadioFragment --pass data--> ViewPagerActivity ( fragment PlayRadio and fragment BlogContent )

NewRadioFragment have some data and i want send to PlayRadio and from Playradio send continue to BlogContent.

If you know solution. Pls help me !
Thanks all.

And My code here :

**public class NewRadioFragment extends Fragment**

```
 btnShowMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (item.getLink_play() != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, item.getLink_play(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,
                            ViewPagerActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString(Constant.STRING_KEY, Desciption);  
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

**ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main_activity);
        setUpView();
    }
```

**public class PlayBlog extends Fragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playradio_layout, container,
                false);
        mContext = container.getContext();
        final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                R.anim.rotate);
        Desciption = getArguments().getString(Constant.STRING_KEY);
        Log.i("", Constant.TAG + Desciption);
        ImageView splash = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.base);
        TextView tvDesciption = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_Marquee);
         tvDesciption.setText(Desciption);
        splash.startAnimation(anim);
        return rootView;
    }
```

UPDATE CODE

I edit my code but NullPoiterException
**public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main_activity);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
        Fragment playRadio = new PlayBlog();
        playRadio.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.pager, playRadio);
        transaction.commit();
        setUpView();
    }
```

And **public class PlayBlog extends Fragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playradio_layout, container,
                false);
        mContext = container.getContext();
        final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                R.anim.rotate);
        Desciption = getArguments().getString(Constant.STRING_KEY);
        Log.i("", Constant.TAG + Desciption);
        ImageView splash = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.base);
        TextView tvDesciption = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_Marquee);
         tvDesciption.setText(Desciption);
        splash.startAnimation(anim);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Update 2

Logcat Error

```
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.tadev.blogradio.main.PlayBlog.onCreateView(PlayBlog.java:36)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:681)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-06 06:14:39.980: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Pass data from `NewRadioFragment` to `PlayBlog` you first need to send Bundle to `ViewPagerActivity` using `putExtras` then call `setArguments` for `PlayBlog` method where you are calling `add or replcase` method for showing  `PlayBlog` fragment in `ViewPagerActivity` Activity.

On `btnShowMore` Button click send Bundle in Intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,
                            ViewPagerActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(Constant.STRING_KEY, Desciption);  
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In `ViewPagerActivity` get Bundle using `getIntent` and call `setArguments` method to send bundle to fragment :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_main_activity);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
```

Now pass `bundle` Bundle to  `PlayBlog` Fragment

Comment: @IrisLouis: in which line you are getting `NullPoiterException` ?

Comment: I test Desciption = bundle.getString(Constant.STRING_KEY);
 Desciption = getArguments().getString(Constant.STRING_KEY);
But nullpointer

Comment: Yes i have remove it. But value null !

Comment: I check on ViewPagerActivity, args has data. but it not pass to playradio

Comment: @IrisLouis: what you are doing in `setUpView` method?

Comment: @IrisLouis: let me know what you missing?

Comment: Class PlayRadio has data but defective NullPointerException at line 
Desciption = getArguments().getString(Constant.STRING_KEY); i don't understand
if you can. you help me fix it !
Update logcat error above

Comment: @IrisLouis: try to use `Fragment playRadio = Fragment.instantiate(ViewPagerActivity.this, PlayBlog.class.getName(), args);` line

Comment: I using Menu mod Navigation Drawer. When start app MainMenu (class config Navigation Drawer ) load NewRadioFragment. I think problem here...

Answer (score 1):

You have to use interface to send datas to its container

Exemple here (last reply) :
[Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity)

Edit : i need more code to send you good example and understand why your fragment start your pager

in NewRadioFragment declare an interface like this

```
// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface Onpassdata // name not fixed 
{
    public void start(String T, int ID);
}
```

declare a member :   private Onpassdata mCallback;

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (Onpassdata) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement Onpassdata");
    }
}

btnShowMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (item.getLink_play() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, item.getLink_play(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               start(Desciption, id);  
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

in pour ViewPagerActivity

```
public ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity
     implements NewRadioFragment.Onpassdata
{

public void start(String T, int ID) {
   // do something whith values
   // and you can Start your BlogContent fragment here
```

}

Comment: in func btnShowMore.setOnClickListener i don't call start(Description) ?

Comment: I have edited because i déclare two parameters in my interface but you can pass one or more parameters. Just adapt the interface and the function

Comment: Ok I test but give me Exception must implement Onpassdata. In ViewPagerActivity i implement Onpassdata

Comment: Can you send the interface déclaration too

Comment: Work if i implement in class MainMenu (class config Navigation Drawer). But  ViewPagerAcvity in start(String T) i show Log("TAG", T) not have data

Comment: You start NewRadioFragment in MainMenu ?

Comment: Yes. Fragment NewRadio get Data from service and i want pass data to another fragments

Comment: I think its why you have no data in ViewPagerAcvity - Your  MainMenu  start ViewPagerAcvity ,and ViewPagerAcvity  start fragments.

Comment: MainMenu start NewRadioFragment, NewRadioFragment start ViewPagerActivity, ViewPagerActivity has two fragment ( PlayRadio and BlogContent )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70365/discussion-between-phil-and-iris-louis).