# Passing from a fragment to its container, looking for clarification

Tags: android, android-fragments

i've read the guide at [Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity) regarding this, but i still can't understand how to do it(still learning Android).

I have an activity that has a button on it, that i want to take it data from an inflated fragment when i click it. The problem is that i am using multiple different fragments, and i don't know how i can generalise referencing them, or call any of them for that matter. Doing some googling, I think i need to be using findFragmentbyId to reference it, but it doesn't seem to like that. I'm not sure on how to proceed

Comment: u need interface mechanism

Comment: i've implemented the onDataPass interface as described in the guide.

Comment: ur problem is sending data to fragment or getting data from it on some event ? or ur not understanding from which fragment data is coming ?\

Comment: when i click the button on the container activity, i don't know what i need to set up in the onClick to be able to collect the data contained in the fragment. I need to know what fragment(of the three the page uses) is currently inflated, and collect the data that i have entered in that fragment. I know i could code the buttons into the fragment to make it easier on myself, but then again i'll still have to pass on the data at some point.

Comment: some design issue.. not coding i think

Comment: How can it be a design issue if i haven't wrote anything yet? I'm just looking to see if someone can explain the datapass interaction to me. If i'm requesting data from the fragment,