# How to access variable in a Activity, from childView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, custom-arrayadapter

I have a view as following hierarchy.

[image]

The main Activity has

```
ArraylistArrayListArraylist()
```

I want to access and change the data of the `Arraylist` from the button of the `Card view`. I'm using Custom ArrayAdapter. So is there are any way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity)

Comment: it was for accessing data from fragment. I have another level. I have Grid Layout with custom Array Adapter in fragment.

Comment: pass the `arraylist` to the fragment from activity ..then pass the `arraylist` to the `arrayadapter` same thing indirectly..

Comment: Make your arraylist as global variable with public access. So in which ever fragment you need this variable you can access it through the activity context.

Comment: you can use getActivity() to access MainActivity rference from fragments

Comment: by doing that will it be able to change Arraylist data in the Activity ?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass your list data from activity to your custom adapter by calling adapter's constructor. See below how you can pass list data and that from adapter.

```
public TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private Context mContext;
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public MovieAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(context, 0 , list);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

.............//use "list" in your adapter

}
```

In activity you have below list.

```
 Arraylist a = new Arraylist();
a.add("test");
a.add("test1");
a.add("test2");
a.add("test3");
TestAdapter testadapter=new TestAdapter(this,a);
```

Now you have that list in adapter and you can use list in your adapter.