# How to get a boolean state from a fragment to an activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, boolean

I have an activity that is the foundation of 2 fragments. The activity chooses which fragment to show based on a boolean. Currently, I have set the boolean state individually to the activity and the fragments like so:

**Activity**:

```
    public boolean setupCompleted = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        {...}     

    if (setupCompleted){
        setFragment(programFragment);
    } else {
        setFragment(setupFragment);
    }

}
```

***setupFragment***:

```
   public boolean setupCompleted = false;

public SetupFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setup, container, false);

    pButton = view.findViewById(R.id.pButton);

    pButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setupCompleted = true;
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Boolean state changed to True!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

The architecture is simple, The **Activity** starts and shows the ***setupFragment*** right away, but when you complete the setup the **Activity** will show the ***programFragment***.

Now my **problem** lies in the fact that I want the button to change the boolean to true so that the main **Activity** can show the ***programFragment*** but I was not able to find any simple explanation on the internet in how to get the boolean state from the ***setupFragment***.

Later I will save the instance state so that the ***setupFragment*** never shows again to a user that already completed the setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this scenario you need to communicate between `Activity` and `Fragment`.

You can do that via `Interface` . Define a `Interface` in `Fragment`

```
    // Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnChnageEvent {
    public void updateCompletedStatus(int value);
}
```

In Fragment :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnChnageEvent) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnChnageEvent");
    }
}
```

When some event happens call

```
 if(mCallback != null){
    //Send the event to the host activity
    mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
 }
```

Implement `Interface` in `Activity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SetupFragment.OnChnageEvent{
  ...

  public void updateCompletedStatus(int value) {

     // Do something here 
     // Change your Fragment 
  }
}
```

For more see [Official Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)

The best approach would be to use `ViewModel` of [Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/). Check [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to have a look. You can communicate between `Activity`, `Fragment` via `ViewModel`

Answer (score 1):

Use interface

```
interface fragmentListener{
   void onComplete();
}

class Activity implements fragmentListener{

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setFragment(new setupFragment(this));
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete(){
   //code here...
  }
}

class setupFragment{
  setupFragment(fragmentListener fl){

  }
}
```