# How do send a data from a fragment to the activity that creates the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity and I create a `fragment` when this activity runs. How do I get the data from the fragment to the `activity` that creates the fragment?

The part where I create an intent in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);

    RoutePlansFragment routePlansFragment = RoutePlansFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransactionUtil.addFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), getFragmentContainerId(), routePlansFragment, routePlansFragment.getFragmentTag());

}
```

This is my fragment:

```
public static RoutePlansFragment newInstance() {
    RoutePlansFragment routePlansFragment = new RoutePlansFragment();
    return routePlansFragment;
}
```

How can I send data from this fragment into activity?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity

Comment: Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977370/1219389), the accepted one isn't a good idea as it leads to tightly coupled code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a callback

in your fragment you have to create a listener

```
public interface DataListener{
    void sendData(String data);
}
```

create a reference

```
    private DataListener mDataListener;
```

and in onAttach you have to caste your activity as DataListener

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof DataListener) {
        mDataListener = (DataListener) context;
    }
}
```

your activiy must implements DataListener

and u can send data from fragment by calling sendData method

Comment: Also worth setting `mDataListener` to `null` in `onDetach()` in the Fragment