# How to implement Fragment-Activity communication by overriting interface?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an application in which an activity launches various fragments. These fragments need to communicate with the parent activity, send some data in this case in the form of a HashMap.

In order for the fragment to send the data back to the parent activity, I have attempted to implement an interface, as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9977370/8288959) and used  [this](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/fragment-to-fragment-communication-with-interfaces) tutorial for further info. Here is my code for my fragment, and for my activity.

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override // Error comes up here
    public void sendDataToActivity(HashMap<Integer, Boolean> myHashmap){
        // do whatever I need here
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyInterface dataPasser;

    public interface MyInterface {
        public void sendDataToActivity(HashMap<Integer, Boolean> myHashmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof MyInterface){
            dataPasser = (MyInterface) context;
        }
    }

}
```

The error I'm getting is "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype". As far as I know this means something in my implementation of the interface in my activity is wrong and doesn't quite make it link with the interface in the fragment; but I've been trying to sort this out for a while, have looked at various answers here and haven't been able to find a way of getting it to work.

Extra information that can be useful is that MyActivity contains a TabLayout which is populated with various instances of MyFragment, I don't know if that might have something to do.

Feel free to ask for further information, code clarifications or point me to an answer that will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the Activity implement your interface

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface
```

Comment: Will mark as answered when the time limit allows me to. Thank you.