# Pass value from fragment to fragment through activity with bottom navigation view

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to pass an auto updating text which is latitude and longitude information from fragment_map to fragment_clocking through MainActivity but the value I get inside fragment_clocking is returned as null with no errors inside Logcat.

I am trying to use bundle to pass the values but I am not sure where and how to declare and call the bundles since I have a bottom navigation view.

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView latitude;
    TextView longitude;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

        latitude = findViewById(R.id.id_latitude);
        longitude = findViewById(R.id.id_longitude);

        bundle.putString("latitudeInfo", String.valueOf(latitude));
        bundle.putString("longitudeInfo", String.valueOf(longitude));

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MapFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_map:
                        selectedFragment = new MapFragment();
                        selectedFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        break;
                    case R.id.navigation_clocking:
                        selectedFragment = new ClockingFragment();
                        selectedFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                        break;

                }

                getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment)
                .commit();
                return true;
                }
        };
    }
```

**MapFragment.java**

```
    public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

    TextView latitude;
    TextView longitude;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);

        latitude = rootView.findViewById(R.id.id_latitude);
        longitude = rootView.findViewById(R.id.id_longitude);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        latitude.setText("Longitude: "+ location.getLongitude());
        longitude.setText("Latitude:    "+ location.getLatitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
```

**ClockingFragment.java**

```
    public class ClockingFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener {

    TextView latitude, longitude;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clocking, null);

        latitude = rootView.findViewById(R.id.id_latitudeLocation);
        longitude = rootView.findViewById(R.id.id_longitudeLocation);

       Bundle bundle = getArguments();
       if(bundle != null){
           String latitudetest = bundle.getString("latitudeInfo");
           String longitudetest = bundle.getString("longitudeInfo");

           latitude.setText(latitudetest);
           longitude.setText(longitudetest);
       }

        return rootView;
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/nav_view"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

**fragment_clocking.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_clocking"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_latitudeLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="TEST PLACEHOLDER"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_longitudeLocation"
            android:layout_below="@+id/id_latitudeLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="TEST PLACEHOLDER"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>
```

**fragment_map.xml**

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_map" />

        <fragment
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_latitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/id_longitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/id_latitude"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Expected result: latitude and longitude value from FragmentMap.java passed through MainActivity.java and displayed in FragmentClocking.java

Actual Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kprBE.jpg

Comment: You put the values of latitude and longitude in the `Bundle` at creation time of your `Activity`. It isn't clear to me where that data should be coming from. Where do you expect to get the longitude and latitude from? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you have a `Fragment` that collects data and you want to pass this data to another `Fragment`, you should implement a callback interface in your `Activity`. The `Fragment` that collects the data should call the method in the `Activity` using the callback interface. The `Activity` should implement the callback interface. The method in the `Activity` should store the data in some member variables when it is called. When the `Activity` starts another `Fragment`, it should add the previously stored data to the "arguments" `Bundle` and then call `setArguments()` to pass the data to the new `Fragment`.

See [Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity) for several possible ways to implement this.