# How to pass data(value) from a fragment to an activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I want to pass a specific String from a fragment to an activity to use it there.
When I am using Intent and Bundle, the value is null. I have tried several methods but can't seem to make it correctly. Can someone help, please?

In my Fragment :

```
Intent testintent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);         
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();         
bundle.putString("testing", "This is a test");         
testintent.putExtras(bundle);`
```

And in my Activity :

```
String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("testing");         
System.out.println("Value is : " + message);`
```

And this is what I am getting as a result in my console :

```
I/System.out: Value is : null
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing data between a fragment and its container activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343241/passing-data-between-a-fragment-and-its-container-activity)

Comment: Edit your question and show the code you use to launch the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Fragment :

```
    val intent = Intent(this, MapsActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("testing", "This is a test")
    startActivity(intent)
```

In the receiving Activity :

```
    val extras = intent.extras
    if (extras != null) {
       val  receivingString = extras.getString("testing")
       System.out.println("Value is : " + receivingString)
    } else {
    
    }
```

Comment: I am coding in java, not in kotlin. The code that you gave e doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Using jave:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("testing", "This is a test");
getActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What do I need to put in my activity then ? I have used this : String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("testing"); But it is still null

Comment: Try this : getIntent().getExtras().getString("testing");